# error while uploading ci project to cpanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I get the error shown below. I tried removing the user, kept the config/database file username and password empty. Then, i created the user `wwwbhak_hajje` and kept the username and pw in the db file respectively.

[image]

Comment: It is generally against the guidelines to have outside links be a major (or only) part of the question or answer. Please edit your question and add the error message into the question as text.

Comment: check with your hosting company for the correct database credentials.